# Scale line width in the unit of the x- and y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot something in `ggplot2` using `geom_segment()`. Both the values on the x- and y-axis are in the same unit. Now I want to scale the linewidth according to a variable which contains how wide the lines should be in the same unit.

Here is some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "start_X" = c(4,4,4,4),
  "start_Y" = c(1,4,6,6),
  "end_X" = c(4,6,5,2),
  "end_Y" = c(6,6,7,9),
  "width" = c(1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.75))
```

I tried plotting like this:

```
# plotting
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start_X, y = start_Y, xend = end_X, yend = end_Y, linewidth = width)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, the line width is not in the same unit. Can I achieve this somehow? I don't want to go through the hassle of calculating polygons for all lines.

Answer (score 1):

Lines and text in ggplot2 don't use the coordinate space to calculate their sizes and widths; these are resolution-dependent. So you might be able to figure it out using a multiplier for a given resolution, but that won't be very robust if you are sizing the output manually.

(I suspect there is a `geom_` in a ggplot2 extension package to do this, but I can't think of one.)

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start_X, y = start_Y, xend = end_X, yend = end_Y, size = width*25)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_size_identity(guide = "legend")
```

(For the moment, as of v3.4.0, ggplot2 doesn't have a `scale_size_linewidth` but we can get what we want with `size`.)

[image]